# How many regenerations does The Master have?

Tags: doctor-who

Prior to the "Timeless Child", Time Lords are known to have 12 regenerations. Then the Master, being of the same species, should have 12 regenerations as well.

Has there been any indication, whether in books or shows, how many regenerations the Master has gone through?

Comment: You're probably better of asking this at the SF&F SE, they've got more expertise, e.g. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226683/is-the-doctor-on-her-3rd-set-of-regenerations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unclear.

In *The Deadly Assassin*, it is stated that the Master has already used up all 12 of his regenerations. In many of his subsequent pre-reboot appearances, including the 1996 film, obtaining a new set of regenerations is his primary goal.

In *The Sound of Drums*, it's revealed that in exchange for his help during the Time War, the Time Lords gave the Master a new body and a new set of regenerations. **It's never stated how many regenerations he was given, how many he has used, or how many he has left.** However, we know of four post-Time War incarnations (played by Derek Jacobi, John Simm, Michelle Gomez, and Sacha Dhawan), so assuming Jacobi's Master is a different incarnation to the 1996 Master, he must have regenerated at least four times.

Just to confuse things even more, the Master has twice cheated death by transferring his consciousness into another person's body (in *The Keeper of Traken* and the 1996 movie), and once refused to regenerate (in *Last of the Time Lords*) only to be resurrected by outside forces (in *The End of Time*). If you count those, then the Master has regenerated **at least 19 times**; if not, then the count is **at least 16**.

Comment: "However, we know of four post-Time War incarnations (played by Derek Jacobi, John Simm, Michelle Gomez, and Sacha Dhawan), so he must have regenerated at least three times.However, we know of four post-Time War incarnations (played by Derek Jacobi, John Simm, Michelle Gomez, and Sacha Dhawan), so he must have regenerated at least three times." Four incarnations after the movie means four regenerations after the move.

Comment: True. It's never stated outright that Professor Yana (the first post-movie incarnation) is a different incarnation to the one from the movie, but it's highly likely.